# Integer being calculated as a number but output as not a number (NaN)?

Tags: javascript

I have a count which increments by one everytime I add a note. When the doc is ready the notes are displayed by creating as many divs as the count.

However I have to parse this count like this:

```
var noteCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("noteCount"));
```

Or else this line:

```
for (var i = 1; i < noteCount + 1; i++) {
```

results in creating 21 divs (if notecount is 2) rather than the required 3.

This is a problem becuase I'm trying to use the count for something else but when I output it in the console it displays as 'NaN'.

Is there a way around this?

edit: If I don't parse the count, it stores correctly as 0, 1, 2 etc.

Comment: `localStorage` stores strings only. If you want to get a number out of it, use `+localStorage.noteCount` instead - also note that the second argument to `parseInt` (the base, usually `10`) is NOT optional.

Comment: You'll have to show us how it becomes `NaN`, as noted in the comment above you'll always get strings from localStorage, everything is just as expected.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("noteCount", noteCount);

Comment: the unary + operator coerces its operand to number. It's equivalent to writing `Number(localStorage.getItem('noteCount'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < +localStorage.noteCount + 1; i++) {
```

That will get just the number out of it. The you wont need parseInt on the first line anymore (Unless you're using it for something else)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

multiplication with 1 will ensure that it will be treated as an integer.

```
for (var i = 1; i < (noteCount * 1) + 1; i++) {

}
```